# how to read file outside codeigniter folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, readfile

i have a project to read file from outside codeigniter directory but in the same server

example :

codeigniter folder path:

opt/xampp/htdocs/yourprogramname/application

but i want to read file from :

purchase/dashboard/filename.txt

my ussual code :

```
  $handle = fopen("purchase/dashboard/filename.txt", "r");
  echo $handle;

  ?>
```

how could i do this in code igniter? i know how to read file from the same directory in codeiginiter (folder resource/etc in application) but when i tried ././ or ../ codeigniter wont read the file content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use `FCPATH`

```
application
purchase
purchase > dashboard
system
index.php
```

File

```
<?php 

if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'purchase/dashboard/filename.txt') {

   $handle = fopen(FCPATH . 'purchase/dashboard/filename.txt', "r");

   echo $handle;

}

?>
```

or

```
<?php 

if (file_exists('/purchase/dashboard/filename.txt') {

   $handle = fopen('/purchase/dashboard/filename.txt', "r");

   echo $handle;

}

?>
```

Codeigniter path functions definitions

```
EXT: The PHP file extension
FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)
SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)
BASEPATH: Path to the system folder
APPPATH: The path to the "application" folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path. Try this,

```
<?php 

 $handle = fopen("/purchase/dashboard/filename.txt", "r");
 echo $handle;

?>
```

Comment: hmm i tried using yours example but i still get eror no such file or directory